# Recordset fails in Access 2007 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am writing a code in Access VBA. I am facing an issue when using a recordset. Here is what I have in the first lines of my code:

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim sql as String

sql = "Select ........"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbReadOnly)
```

The program fails in the second line " set rst= .....". I added the following references:
Visual Basic for Applications,
Microsoft Access 12.0 Object library,
OLE automation,
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library

But the program still fails in the second line. Is there anything else I should do???
Thanks,

Comment: I also tried Dim rst As DAO.Recordset. but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currentdb is DAO code but you state you have an ADO reference.   Remove the ADO reference and add the Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Object Library.

If this were Access 2000, 2002 or 2003 I'd suggest adding the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library.

Comment: I removed the ADO reference. Now I have the following references: Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Access 12.0 Object library, OLE automation, and Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Object Library. But the problem still remains. Any idea??